# Keeping a generated variable after form submit on same page

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, csrf

This is a bit hard to explain, I have a register form on the same page as my register script and i am using CSRF protection by use of token. When the page is generated the token is generated into a SESSION variable. I have a function that is executed when POST data is submitted to register the user. When the data is submitted the script regenerates another token so i have no way of checking the token against my session variable. Please take a look at the code below if i REMOVE the function wrapper then everything works fine. The reason i have the function is to display errors in a certain div. All my PHP classes work fine so that is not the problem but if you need to see the code just ask.

Code:

```
<?php
require_once "assets/php/core/init.php";
require_once "assets/php/core/autoload.php";

function register(){
    if(Input::exists()){
        if(Token::check(Input::get("token"))){
            echo 'Token Checked';
            $spamField = Input::get("automated");
            if(!isset($spamField)){
                $Validation = new Validation();
                $Validation->validate(array(
                    'username' => array(
                        'key' => 'Username',
                        'value' => Input::get("username"),
                        'min' => '1',
                        'max' => '32',
                        'alphanumeric' => true,
                        'required' => true
                    ),
                    'email' => array(
                        'key' => 'E-Mail',
                        'value' => Input::get("email"),
                        'max' => '128',
                        'email' => true,
                        'required' => true
                    ),
                    'password' => array(
                        'key' => 'Password',
                        'value' => Input::get("password"),
                        'required' => true
                    )
                ));

                if($Validation->passed()){
                    echo 'OK';
                } else {
                    foreach($Validation->errors() as $error){
                        echo $error . '<br>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Codemy - Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core/core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/core/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/extra/fontello/css/fontello.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/extra/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/core/core.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div id="logo"><a href="./">Codemy</a></div>

            <ul class="right links">
                <li><a href="#" class="fade-in">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fade-in">Premium</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fade-in">Explore</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-red fade-in toggle">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box-half white-background">
                <form class="form" method="post" action="register.php">
                    <div class="form-header clearfix">
                        <div class="column half">
                            <h1 class="form-title left">Create an Account for Free</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column half">
                            <p class="right form-note">Have an account? <a href="login.php" class="red
                            secondary">Click
                                    Here</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="box-two-thirds">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label form="username" class="form-label">Username:</label>
                                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-input fade-in width-full"
                                       placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <label form="email" class="form-label">E-Mail:</label>
                                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="form-input fade-in width-full"
                                       placeholder="E-Mail" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <label form="password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-input fade-in
                            width-full" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-medium btn-primary btn-red
                            width-full fade-in" value="Get Started For Free">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="text" name="automated" class="hidden">
                                <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <p><?php register(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-footer">
                        <p class="form-note">By signing up, you agree to our <a href="#" class="red
                        secondary">Terms of Service</a></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <p class="left no-margin" style="line-height: 75px;">Built In Chicago | &copy; 2014 Codemy</p>

            <div class="right">
                <ul class="footer-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this just a scope issue? you say this code works if you dont wrap the code in a function, so it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to manually keep a record of the unique Token that was generated before. This way you can check `POST`'s against the "previousToken" and use the new Token to do other stuff.

Could look like this:

`$_SESSION['previousToken'] = $_SESSION['Token'];`

Does this help you in any way?

Comment: Remember that you need to do this before the new Token is generated. You could also do this after a new Token is generated, but then you would need to make sure you're not overwriting your control data all the time.

Comment: Ya... I dont really know where to put this could you help me out any more?

Comment: Can you include or explain where the Tokens are being generated, and when these methods are being called in your application?

Comment: The token is being generated in the form below. When the token is generated it stores the value in a session called "token" the if() statement checks if the hidden input value that holds the token matches the session data.

Comment: What if you just put the <?php register(); ?> before the generation of the Token? Can you explain why you put the call to the function so late inside an already generated form by the way?